# This code is not run, getelementbyid return null

Tags: ckeditor, getelementbyid

This code is not run, getelementbyid return null

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (e) {
         document.getElementById(e.editor.name + '_preview').innerHTML = e.editor.getData();
         var a = $('#' + e.editor.name + '_preview').height();
         $('#' + e.editor.name + '_txt').val(a.toString());
         e.editor.on
                      ('change'
                      , function (ev) {
                          document.getElementById(e.editor.name + '_preview').innerHTML = ev.editor.getData();
                          var a = $('#' + e.editor.name + '_preview').height();
                          $('#' + e.editor.name + '_txt').val(a.toString());
                      }
                      );
     });

    var config = { extraPlugins: 'onchange' }; 
    CKEDITOR.replace('contents', config);
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Code should be understandable now.

Comment: Could you reformat your question? The code is imposible to read and it's unclear what you are asking about.

Comment: This code has lost its line breaks, so a helpful editor cannot fix it for you. Voting to close for now, please be willing to repair it!

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link for [instanceCreated](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceCreated). Although instance is created, it hasn't been initialized yet. If you want to work with the editor, please use the [instanceReady](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceReady) event.

Please also make sure that element with id `e.editor.name + '_preview'` actually exists because another reason for your problem may be that such id doesn’t exist.